# Não está exibindo todos valores do array na tela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, json, array

Fiz uma chamada para  pegar valores JSON vindos de um código externo(PHP). No `console.log`, mostra todos os dados certinho, mais quando vou passar do jquery para exibir na tela, ele só me retorna o último valor do array.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  var url = "https://siteteste98874.com/select.php";
            $.getJSON(url, function(result){
                console.log(result);
                $.each(result, function(i, field){
                    var nome = field.nome_produto;
                    $('.nome td').text(nome);
                });
            });
});
```

```
<h3>Todas Lojas</h3>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="nome">
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

No `console.log` mostra todos  os nomes das lojas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já na tela só é mostrado o último valor do array

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema está exatamente nessa linha:

```
$('.nome td').text(nome);
```

Sempre que ela é executada, o texto do `<td>` é substituído por um novo nome, por isso você só vê o último.

Você precisa usar o `createElement()` e `appendChild()` pra inserir uma nova `<tr>` e `<td>` a cada volta do laço.